# Ubuntu on Oracle Virtual box becomes unresponsive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an instance of Ubuntu x64 16.04 guest running on a Windows 10 x64 Host.  If I leave it running for an hour or two, it seems to lock and I can't get it to respond.  I'm typically running it in as a normal window or full screen mode, not as scaled mode or seamless mode.  I am running it with 3 virtual screens.  I've clicking on the Ubuntu screen and waving the mousepointer around.  I've also tried sending Ctrl+Alt+Del to it via the Input menu and with the Host+Del button.  The screen just remains black until I power off the virtual machine.

I have all the power suspend, etc. settings turned off as far as I can figure out.  The UI for the powersettings is kind of confusing.

[image: Ubuntu Brightness & Lock]

I don't see a way to turn off the *Turn off screen when inactive for: 5 minutes.*

There's nothing visual that changes when you toggle the lock setting on and off, but since the *Lock screen after* is disabled, so I would assume that it's off.

Here are my power settings:

[image: Ubuntu Power Settings]

Here are my Security and Privacy settings:

[image: Ubuntu Security and Privacy Settings]

Comment: Where is the VM's power button?  I see the Start button on Virtual Box manager.  I've clicked it when the machine was unresponsive, but it didn't do anything.